# How to remove exception message automatically after it appears from magento site(Updated)

Tags: magento-1.9, exception, messages, zipcode

I am building the magento site named www.bookslab.in. I want to remove the alert message "Above field is mandatory". It appears when users clicks on ADD TO CART button without checking the zipcode which is mandatory for every users. I want to remove this alert message because it does not need when user know that the Zipcode field is mandatory. I am attaching the screenshot for better understanding. I had added the cod.phtml code & updated my screenshot image to understand better.

cod.phtml

```
<?php


$msgData = Mage::helper('netgo_cod')->getConfigData(); 
if($msgData['zip_status'] == 1){
?>
<div class="input-box">
    <div class="z-btn">
        <label>Zip Code : </label><input type="text" placeholder="Enter your pincode" value="" name="cod" class="product-custom-option required-entry" id="cod" size="29" style='color:black; font-size:12px'>
        <button type="button" onclick="checkCOD();" name="zip-check" title="Check" class="button" id="zip-check"><span><span>Check</span></span></button>
    </div>
    <div id="cod_msg"></div>
</div>

<script>
    function checkCOD(){
             var zipcode;
        var cod = $('cod').value;
        if(cod == ''){
            $('cod_msg').update('<span class="cod-error"><?php echo $msgData['emp_msg']; ?></span>');
            return
        }else{
            $('cod_msg').update('<img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl( Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB, true ).'media/cod/img/ajax-loader-2.gif';?>">'); 
            new Ajax.Request('<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl().'netgo/cod/check';?>', {
                method:'post',
                parameters: {zipcode: cod}, 
                onSuccess: function(transport) {
                    var response = transport.responseText || "no response text";
                    $('cod_msg').update(response);

                    if(response.search('Delivery of the books not available')!=-1)
                                        {
                                          zipcode='checked';
                                          jQuery('.btn-cart').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
                                        }
                                      else
                                      {
                                      jQuery('.btn-cart').removeAttr('disabled');

                                      }

                },
                onFailure: function() { alert('Something went wrong...'); }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `setTimeOut` jQuery function to hide the message after it appears to users.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.btn-cart, #zip-check').click(function(){
        setTimeout(function() {
            jQuery("#cod_msg").update('')
        }, 5000);
    });
});
```

Here `5000` is the time in milliseconds, it defines 5 seconds, you can set it as per your requirements.

Comment: Okzz i will check your method & get back to you

Comment: In which file i have to add this code & on which line

Comment: You can put this code in `app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\view\addtocart.phtml`

Comment: Okzz i will check

Comment: Thank you @Jaimin that works for me & sorry for the late reply

Comment: but one problem is occuring @Jaimin. Your code is working on ADD TO CART button but it is not working for CHECK button

Comment: You need to add your button's class in `jQuery('.btn-cart, YOUR_BUTTON_CLASS')` and it will work.

Comment: Okzz i will check & get back to u

Comment: Still it is not working @Jaimin

Comment: can you please suggest me cod.phtml code which is above

Comment: That works for me, but now after getting the message & fading it out after 5 sec, again when i click on CHECK button, the message is not coming

Comment: Check with updated code.

Comment: Its not working @Jaimin

Comment: i had tried again with your updated code above but still it does not work. When i used your updated code then message is not coming once its get pop up i.e second time it is not coming when i press CHECK button of zipcode